# Only push the object which is not in the array yet

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my function:

```
const multiSelect = value => {
    let tmpArr = [...selectedPeople];

    if (tmpArr.length === 0) {
      tmpArr.push(value);
    } else {
      tmpArr.map(item => {
        if (item.id !== value.id) {
          tmpArr.push(value);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      });
    }
    setSelectedPeople(tmpArr);
  };
```

I want to check the array for the new value by comparing it with all items. If `value === item` item the loop function should `return`, but if the value is not in the array yet, it should push it.

This is a big problem for me but I assume it is a small problem for you guys.

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't use `map` where `forEach` would be more suitable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if the array doesn't contain an item with the same `id`:

```
const multiSelect = value => {
  const tmpArr = [...selectedPeople];
  
  if(tmpArr.every(item => item.id !== value.id)) {
    tmpArr.push(value);
  }

  setSelectedPeople(tmpArr);
};
```

However, this means that you're duplicating the array needlessly, while causing a re-render, that won't do a thing. So check if the item is already a part of `selectedPeople` by using `Array.some()`, and if it does use `return` to exit the function early. If it's not continue with cloning, and updating the state:

```
const multiSelect = value => {
  if(tmpArr.some(item => item.id === value.id)) {
    return;
  }

  const tmpArr = [...selectedPeople];
  
  tmpArr.push(value);

  setSelectedPeople(tmpArr);
};
```

Comment: I got it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if the item is already in the array. Also, there's no need to make a copy of the source array:

```
const multiSelect = value => {
    if (!selectedPeople.find(item => item.id === value.id))
        setSelectedPeople(selectedPeople.concat(value))
}
```

Comment: I got it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

```
const
    multiSelect = value => setSelectedPeople([
        ...selectedPeople,
        ...selectedPeople.some(({ id }) => id === value.id)
            ? []
            : [value]
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have gained new knowledge.